# Is it possible to change device type for next version in itunes for app?

Tags: xcode, itunes

I have implemented an app only in iPad compatibility. And I have uploaded the app on itunes.

Now if I want to make compatibility of app for iPhone and iPad both then it is possible for next version?

Any suggestion please...?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: What's the question? Is it that you don't know how to do this, or you're worried about changing it at the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
You must change Devices : Universal

This could enable you to create an initial version that targets either iPhone or iPad, and then later switch to Universal and submit it as a new version. The App Store will then automatically recognize that the new version of the app is Universal, and you would need to add additional screenshots, etc. for the new devices.